# How do I get the previous number of a number in a set?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, set

My problem is that I don't know how to get the number that is less than but closest to a number X in a set.
For example, if a set has the numbers 0, 8, and 10, I want to get the number 0 in relation to the number 8.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int X = 8;

set<int> str;
str.insert(0);
str.insert(X);
str.insert(10);

}
```

and I want to get the numbers 0 and 10 only by using X.
The two methods that I have tried are:

`cout << *(str.lower_bound(X)--) << ' ' << *(str.lower_bound(X)++) << endl;`

and

`cout << *((str.find(X))--) << ' ' << *((str.find(X))++) << endl;`

and none of these seems to work; They both output '8 8' instead of the desired '0 10'.

How do I get the numbers in a set in relations to the numbers around them?

Comment: Prefix (e.g. `++i`) and suffix (e.g. `i++`) have very different semantics. Worth noting is that the suffix operation returns the *old* value. _So e.g. `str.find(X)--` will return the iterator for `X`.

Comment: As for a way to solve your problem, why not simply `auto prev = str.find(X); --prev;`? After that it should "point" to the preceding value in the set.

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend the ++ and the --, like

```
cout << *(--(str.find(X))) << ' ' << *(++(str.find(X))) << endl;
```